# Best practice for Installing missing 32-bit package on a 64-bit Fedora Linux

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, rpm, fedora-13

I am using Fedora 13 64-bit. After reading few posts online it seems that most of 32-bit packages and libraries can easily be installed using the following command:

```
yum install *packagename*.i686
```

which is great. However, due to some constraints I was in need of 32-bit version of wireshark and wireshark-gnome packages. Installing wireshark was not an issue since the default 64-bit repo already had that package:

```
yum list | grep wireshark
wireshark.i686                           1.2.17-1.fc13                  updates 
wireshark.x86_64                         1.2.17-1.fc13                  updates 
wireshark-devel.i686                     1.2.17-1.fc13                  updates 
wireshark-devel.x86_64                   1.2.17-1.fc13                  updates 
wireshark-gnome.x86_64                   1.2.17-1.fc13                  updates
```

but there was no corresponding wireshark-gnome package in the default repo. What is the best way to install 32-bit packages when one such is not available in the default repo. I see that [F13 updates](http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/13/i386/wireshark-1.2.17-1.fc13.i686.rpm) repo has the wireshark-gnome package that I want.

Comment: The best method is to install it by hand.  If you found the package you want you should install it.

Answer (score 0):

As a warning installing the 32 bit version of the package means you're going to have to install every 32 bit dependency that might exist for that package, so there may be additional packages that you end up installing on the system. The repository you have linked to doesn't seem to have any metadata so you would need to install it manually after you download it via the [RPM](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/index.html) command. If this is on a local desktop I'd suggest creating a virtual 32 bit machine and working out of that.